# HTTPI::SSLError and Yodlee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, savon

I've encountered a strange problem. I'm using Savon to connect to Yodlee's API but when trying to initiate the client object I get:

HTTPI::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=unknown state

I've already tried stuff like ssl_verify_mode: :none etc. But nothing seems to work. Most of similiar bugs I saw on the Web had sth. like state=SSLv3 at the end of the error but mine is different. Does anyone has a single clue what is going on here? Thx for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your environment looks like, but here are some things to check ...

1. You need a path to your ca-bundle.crt .... this is the bundle of trust relationships from your cert provider.
2. I am not absolutely positive, but I believe that Yodlee only handles ssl_verify_mode of peer.

Here is a portion of code that works for me to generate a Savon v2 client to connect to Yodlee:

```
    Savon.client do

      ... Lots of configurations here ....

      ssl_cert_file CERT_PATH
      ssl_verify_mode :peer
      open_timeout 90
      read_timeout 90

    end
```

where CERT_PATH points to my ca-bundle.crt file.